# How to from one SSIS project execute sql task that is located in another SSIS project

Tags: ssis, parent-child

I have two SSIS projects within the same folder - let's call them Parent.dtsx and Child.dtsx.

Child solution has many SQL task split by different Sequence Containers.

What I need to do is to (in Parent) execute SQL task from (Child). I don't want to execute whole Child solution, only part of it.

I has been searching for a proper solution for a while, but I haven't found a proper answer yet.

Every Parent-Child solution I've seen presents how to execute whole solution (Child) within Parent one.

I tried to execute selected tasks from Child solution by passing the SQL task ID to the Execute Package Task but if failed. Probably, I don't want to pass any variables from Child to Parent - I just need to execute selected SQL tasks from Child.

I'm a beginner when it comes to SSIS.

Thanks, 
Karol

Comment: If you don't want to pass a variable, which can be tested by the called package, there is no way to select use the execute package task and select a task within the package to execute. You may want to copy the package delete all the extraneous tasks and then execute the new version that only contains the task you want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

> Every Parent-Child solution I've seen presents how to execute whole
>   solution (Child) within Parent one.

That's because that's the only way it works.  There is no way to call only some elements of a child package from a parent package; you can only execute the entire child package, unless you want to get into some extremely complicated low-level coding in a script task.

You need to decide where your tipping point is, and do one of the following (whichever is more desirable in your case):

1. Copy the SQL Task from your Child package and paste it into your parent package, and just have everything in one package.
2. Modify your child package so that you can pass it a variable, and only execute certain tasks based on the variable that is passed.
3. Make your solution even more modular:  Take the Task you want to execute out of the child package, and put it in its own package all by itself.   Then you can call that third package from the child package, and/or you call it directly from the parent package.

Those are your best options.

EDIT:  An idea of how to do option 2 - Add a variable to the child package.  In the precedence constraints before each task, check the variable, and if it isn't a certain value, then skip that step.

In other words, from your first step, (which may have to be a "dummy" script, because it is going to get executed every time the package starts no matter what), you have multiple constraints coming out.  One that says if the first step is complete and the variable equals some value, go to step 2.  Another that says if the first step is complete and the variable equals some other value, go to step 3, and so on and so on.

And then from your parent package, you pass whatever variable value will tell the child package to only execute the task you want to execute.

It ends up looking pretty ugly, because you have precedence constraints all over the place, but we have used it in the past and it works.   It won't be too bad if you only have two possible paths you want the execution to take.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately I was expecting one like this :/. Option 1 doesn't suit me at all. But when it comes to the Option 2 - could you recommend some approach I may use to do that as I don't want to pass any results from the sql task (this task creates some tables in db) I just need to be able to execute this task to perform other modifications over the created table with my Parent solution. How to create this kind of variable that might work for me? I don't want to pass the whole sql code from this sql script to variable as a way around. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added a third option to my answer.

Comment: Hmm 3rd option seems to be the best one - I can have two Child solutions pointing at the same sql script, so when it comes to modifications I wouldn't need to change anything within SSIS's solutions - only SQL script. Instead I will have some more solutions in the folder but I can live with that. Thank you so much for the idea :)